# bootstrap carousel acting weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

so i created website from [this template](https://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524962-corlate-free-responsive-business-html-template) and recently i found that the carousel is not sliding automatically except i first click prev or next button.

i already check javascript from this template and not finding anything that related to this carousel except for adjusting timing.

and i just can't make this carousel to keep cycling when i put my mouse inside the carousel, i tried to using pause option but not working

also my carousel are only containing image, so i want to add `<a href='#'>` to warp my image so when user click the carousel image it will direct them to the link that i already prepared...

here is [my website](http://sm-trust.com/)

Comment: I would recommend you to create an example in JSFIDDLE or CODEPEN and reproduce the error so that people can look in to it and help you. Most of people do not have the time to go through your website to find the possible issue.

Comment: I get JavaScript errors in the browser when I load your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main.js file put a space in between the #main-slider and .carousel right now it looks like this:

```
//#main-slider
$(function(){
    $('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 8000
    });
});
```

And it should look like this:

```
//#main-slider
$(function(){
    $('#main-slider .carousel').carousel({
        interval: 8000
    });
});
```

If you are not going to have anything in your carousel and want a `<a>` tag in there you could just put it in the item and then position it absolutely so it overlays the entire item.  You will want to set the z-index to -1 so you can still use your carousel controls like so:

Html:

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url('http://sm-trust.com/imagesartikel/v0KO6zeQfA2016-01-29n.jpg')">
<a href="first.html"></a>
</div>
<div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://sm-trust.com/imagesartikel/8fXdR35LuO2016-01-29n.jpg')">
<a href="second.html"></a>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#main-slider .item a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/2sua0ex2/)

Comment: wow thank you bro... you are awesome, i spend all night trying to figure it out... i think i need to learn css and javascript